# Speed up poster image overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

Using FFMPG I'm creating a poster image from a video and adding an watermark/overlay to the poster. The following works great with small video files, but destroys my CPU with 1080p files.

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i preview.mp4 -i play-button.png \
-filter_complex overlay='(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2', \
scale='min(640\, iw):-1' -vframes 1 poster.jpg
```

Is there any way to speed this up? Or should I look to another solution for the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar yours. But i use -s to set the output resolution for the image, and -f image2 for rendering. This commands works fine for me:

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i preview.mp4 -i play-button.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -vframes 1 -s 640x360 -f image2 -y poster.jpg
```

Comment: Same problem. I'm receiving this error: `[swscaler @ 0x7fcd0e12f800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0x7fcd0c7800c0] [framesync @ 0x7fcd0c7801a8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping. Last message repeated 1607 times` I had to press `q` to stop it before it crashed my system